# Node.js on Windows Azure IIS using IISNode: How to set startup file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, iis, iisnode

I am using IISNode to server Node.js files over IIS on Windows Azure. But when I try to access the server path using `http://127.0.0.1/mysite/node/` its throwing the following error

```
iisnode encountered an error when processing the request.

HRESULT: 0x2
HTTP status: 500
HTTP reason: Internal Server Error
```

And in the log file generated in iisnode folder it shows the following error:

```
Application has thrown an uncaught exception and is terminated:
Error: Cannot find module 'D:\Project\Files\mysite\node"'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:286:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\iisnode\interceptor.js:210:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:434:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:452:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:475:10)
```

But when I try this path `http://127.0.0.1/mysite/node/app.js` it executes the app.js file. However, I do not want to reveal the app.js file name in the URL. Can I set this file as the default file or startup file when I use this path `http://127.0.0.1/mysite/node/`?

---

**UPDATE**

Further to my answer below:

```
    <rule name="DynamicContent">
      <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True"/>
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="node/main.js"/>
    </rule>
```

This block of code in config is preventing calls to any .net files instead it is redirecting to node for execution. How can i redirect to node only when the URL contains `/node/` at the end like `http://127.0.0.1/mysite/node/`?

Answer (score 1):

I think [this](https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/issues/160) solution works.

Evaluating now...

---

**UPDATE**

```
    <rule name="DynamicContent">
      <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True"/>
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="node/main.js"/>
    </rule>
```

This block of code in config is preventing calls to any .net files and it is redirecting to node for execution.

**How can i redirect to node only when the URL contains `/node/` at the end like `http://127.0.0.1/mysite/node/`?**

Answer (score 0):

We can leverage `location` element in web.config file as deciding that all files in a particular directory are supposed to be treated as node.js applications.

Here is my sites directory figure in iis:

[image]

And here is the content of `web.config`:

`<configuration>
    <location path="node">
        <system.webServer>
            <handlers>
                <add name="iisnode" path="*.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
            </handlers>

        </system.webServer>
    </location>
</configuration>`

And the URL like`http://localhost /mysite/node` will handled by iisnode as configured in `web.config`.

And the others will not be effected by iisnode, for example in this test,
`http://localhost /mysite/php/index.php` still run PHP script.

For more infomation, we can see in [Hosting node.js applications in IIS on Windows](http://tomasz.janczuk.org/2011/08/hosting-nodejs-applications-in-iis-on.html)